# JSONException on getting data from server

Tags: php, android, json

i' m getting data from a online database, i have no connection problem or anything like that,but i'm catching always this excpetion into this condition:

- `if (!result.contains("null")){...}` .

  ```
                  JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
                  for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                      JSONObject job = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                  }

              } catch (JSONException e) {
                  Log.e("Parser Problem", e.toString() + result);
              }
          }
  ```

my logcat shows me the Log.e(...)

```
 E/Parser Problem(7300): org.json.JSONException: Value <script of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

this is my php script with a query inside my server:

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT name
FROM users
HAVING name = John";                    
$result = $connection->query($query);
    while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $output[]=$row;
    }
    echo json_encode($output);
    $connection = null;
?>
```

thanks a lot.

Comment: Try replacing this `JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);` by `JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(result);`

Comment: Clearly your error message shows html `<script...` so your php is not **only** outputting the json. Please show the complete file for a solution

Comment: @user574632 the script you see is the complete file.

Comment: Well your error message shows what looks like a javascript redirect in an html block, The above php is **not** outputting that, so some other code must be included somehow

Comment: Well i really dont know where this is comming from, for all i know you might have some weird .htaccess redirecting to another page all together = all i do know is that the above php is not outputting the code shown in your error message, so **something** else is.

Comment: For a little more info, why not log the `result` and add it to your question so we can see the complete output

Comment: is that update from logging result as i suggested? or by visiting the url in your browser? Because the latter is not very helpfull

Comment: well, i tried to print the result of the script but it shows me this `<script type="text/javascript">
             <!--
           window.location = "http://"
             //-->
        </script>`

Comment: Ok, well please log the result as i suggested, as i expect the above error is simply down to a lack of post data (visiting the url wont post anything, it will make a GET request), and is not necessarily related to your actual problems

Comment: can you tell me how i can do, i' m new on json and php, to log the result?

Comment: Well i am not experianced in android, but `result` is just a string, so basically you just need to log or display that somehow so you can post it here. Perhaps you already did in your earlier comment starting `<script type=...`

Comment: i know that,I thought you wanted something else, anyway, have you understand the mistake?

Comment: Ok its as i said earlier - some other code is outputing to the browser - that is html being returned, and there is **no** evidnace of html in your php in the question. Are you posting directly to the php file above, eg http://example.com/myfile.php or are you using some kind of framework.

Comment: wait i'm posting the entire class.

Comment: OK, well i doubt that public_html should be part of the url. My guess is your server is then redirecting to the correct url via javascript, and its this js redirect that you are getting in your responce. Please double and treble check the url is correct. For example when you visit it in your browser, does the url in the address bar stay the same, or does it change to the url in the jsblock `window.location = "http://` <--this url

Comment: well, it changes in `window.location = "http://` how i can fix this?

Comment: In your android code, post to the correct url. Not knowing your actual live url, i cant really test, but its probably the url in that javascript block. post directly to that url in your android code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you are working with `JSON` you have to make sure that **output contained by your web file is must be in `JSON`**..

There is HTML part in your output..
so it can not be converted into JSON..

there is problem with PHP file.
Your **PHP file contains HTML form**.. remove it and run your code...

Comment: can you tell me how i can change this?

Comment: try to run your your file in web browser with static lang and long defined.. and try to check what output it gives

Answer (score 0):

```
proxy for post method:

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.StatusLine;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import com.youflik.youflik.utils.Util;
import android.util.Log;


public class HttpPostClient {
    private static final String TAG = "HttpClient";
    public static int statuscode;

    public static JSONObject sendHttpPost(String URL, JSONObject jsonObjSend) {

        try {
            DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();


            HttpPost httpPostRequest = new HttpPost(URL);

            StringEntity se;

            se = new StringEntity(jsonObjSend.toString());

            // Set HTTP parameters
            httpPostRequest.setEntity(se);
            httpPostRequest.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
            httpPostRequest.setHeader("Accept-Charset", "utf-8");


            long t = System.currentTimeMillis();
            HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) httpclient.execute(httpPostRequest);
            Log.i(TAG, "HTTPResponse received in [" + (System.currentTimeMillis()-t) + "ms]");


            StatusLine statusline = response.getStatusLine();
            statuscode = statusline.getStatusCode();


            // Get hold of the response entity (-> the data):
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            if (entity != null) {
                // Read the content stream
                InputStream instream = entity.getContent();

                // convert content stream to a String

                try {

                    String resultString= convertStreamToString(instream);
                    instream.close();
                    // Transform the String into a JSONObject
                    JSONObject jsonObjRecv = new JSONObject(resultString);

                    return jsonObjRecv;

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            } 

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }


    private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line = null;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("converted string is "+sb.toString());
        return sb.toString();
    }



}
proxy for get method
public class HttpGetClient {
    public static int statuscode;

    public static JSONObject sendHttpPost(String URL){

        try {
            HttpClient httpclient;
            httpclient = HttpClientSingalTon.getHttpClienttest();
            HttpGet httpGetRequest = new HttpGet(URL);
            if(Util.API_TOKEN !=null)
            {
                System.out.println(Util.API_TOKEN);

            }

            HttpResponse response;

            //  System.out.println("executing request " + httpGetRequest.getRequestLine());
            //  System.out.println("executing request " + httpGetRequest.getMethod());
            //  System.out.println("executing request " + httpGetRequest.getFirstHeader("X-Auth-Token"));
            //  System.out.println("executing request Tsting  " + httpGetRequest.getHeaders("X-Auth-Token"));

            response = httpclient.execute(httpGetRequest);

            StatusLine statusline = response.getStatusLine();
            statuscode = statusline.getStatusCode();
            // Examine the response status
            Log.i("Praeda",response.getStatusLine().toString());

            // Get hold of the response entity
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            // If the response does not enclose an entity, there is no need
            // to worry about connection release

            if (entity != null) {

                // A Simple JSON Response Read
                InputStream instream = entity.getContent();

                String result= convertStreamToString(instream);

                // now you have the string representation of the HTML request
                instream.close();
                JSONObject jsonObjRecv = new JSONObject(result);

                return jsonObjRecv;

            }


        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }


    private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
        /*
         * To convert the InputStream to String we use the BufferedReader.readLine()
         * method. We iterate until the BufferedReader return null which means
         * there's no more data to read. Each line will appended to a StringBuilder
         * and returned as String.
         */
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line = null;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
        return sb.toString();
    }       


}
```

Comment: Just copy & past is not a good approach without any explanation of what you posted..

Comment: bro i did'nt copy pasted it  , i clearly mentioned it... 1st one was for post method and second was for get method .. what more details you need

Comment: A bit more explanation would be appreciated :) like in this what will  protect from stucking in JSONException..

Comment: @SmartphoneDeveloper If you want to add explanation, you may edit the answer.